# Application of extension of the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: probability

In the textbook *Probablity: Theory and Examples* by Durrett, he mentioned one theorem which extends the second Borel-Cantelli lemma and sharpens its conclusion:

> **Theorem 2.3.8** If $A_1 , A_2 , \cdots$ are pairwise independent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(A_n)=\infty$, then as $n\to\infty$, $$\sum_{m=1}^n 1_{A_m} \left/\sum_{m=1}^n\right. P(A_m) \to 1 \text{ a.s. }$$

Then he says:

> The moral o the proof of Theorem 2.3.8 is that if you want to show that $X_n/c_n\to 1 \text{ a.s. }$ for sequences $c_n,X_n\ge 0$ that are increasing, it is enough to prove the result for a subsequence $n(k)$ that has $ c_{n(k+1)}\left/c_{n(k)}\right.\to 1$

I am quite puzzled about it. How did he get that conclusion? For example, he gives one exercises:

> **Exercise 2.3.2** Let $0\le X_1\le X_2 \cdots$ be random variables with $EX_n\sim an^\alpha$ with $a,\alpha > 0$ and $\text{var}(X_n)\le Bn^\beta$ with $\beta < 2\alpha$. Show that $X_n / n^\alpha\to a$ a.s.

Can you give me some hints about how to use that theorem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This does not require any result from Probability Theory. Suppose we have sequences $c_n,x_n\ge 0$ that are increasing such that for some  for subsequence $n(k)$ we have $ \frac {x_{n_k}} {c_{n_k}} \to c$ and $c_{n(k+1)}\left/c_{n(k)}\right.\to 1$. Any integer $n$ greater the $n(1)$ lies between $n(k)$ and $n(k+1)$ for some $k$. Now, $$\frac {x_n} {c_n} \leq \frac {x_{n(k+1)}} {c_{n_k}}=\frac {x_{n(k+1)}} {c_{n(k+1)}}\frac {c_{n(k+1)}} {c_{n(k)}}.$$ This gives $\lim \sup \frac {x_n} {c_n} \leq c$. Similarly, we get $\lim \inf \frac {x_n} {c_n} \geq c$ so $\frac {x_n} {c_n}  \to c$.

For the exercise consider $Y_n=X_n-EX_n$. Note that $ E(Y_n^{2}/n^{\alpha}) \leq B n^{\beta -2\alpha }$. I wil let you check that if $n(k)=k^{j}$ with $j(2\alpha -\beta) >2$ then $\sum E(Y_{n(k)}^{2}/n(k)^{\alpha}) <\infty$.  This implies that $\sum Y_{n(k)}^{2}/n(k)^{\alpha} <\infty$ almost surely, so $Y_{n(k)}^{2}/n(k)^{\alpha} \to 0$ almost surely. Can you finish?

I

Comment: So, if $n(k) = k^j , j(2\alpha - \beta) > 2$, then $\sum E(Y_{n(k)}^2 / n(k)^\alpha) \le\sum Bn(k)^{\beta - 2\alpha} < \sum Bk^{-2} < \infty$, and we get $Y_{n(k)}^2 / n(k)^\alpha \to 0$ a.s.. By the theorem above we get $Y^2/n^\alpha\to 0$ a.s., which equal to $(X_n - EX_n)^2/n^\alpha \to 0$ a.s.. So, can we directly get the conclusion $(X_n - EX_n)/n^\alpha \to 0$ a.s. ?

Comment: @robothead $|(X_n-EX_n) /n^{\alpha}| =(\sqrt {(X_n-EX_n)^{2} /n^{\alpha}}) \frac 1 {n^{\alpha}/2} \to 0$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy Oh yes! Sorry to reply late.